# errors in django tests

Tags: python, django

im trying to run the following test but im not sure why its not working since when tests are ran a test db is created and that means that the newly created item gets an id of 1 but im still getting an error that no object matches the query

model

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class Post(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text[:50]
```

tests

```
from django.test import TestCase

from .models import Post

# Create your tests here.


class PostModelTest(TestCase):

    def setup(self):
        post = Post.objects.create(text="just a test")

    def test_text_content(self):
        post = Post.objects.get(id=1)
        expected_obect_name = f'{post.text}'
        self.assertEqual(expected_obect_name, 'just a test')
```

here's the error
[image]

Comment: unrelated, but the `expected_obect_name = f'{post.text}'` is just a waste of cpu cycles - do the simple obvious thing instead: `self.assertEqual(post.text, 'just a test')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should name method [`setUp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUp) not `setup`. It's case-sensetive. But it's probably will not solve your problem, since django doesn't reset auto id for each `TestCase` class. So if you have another test case with same code the error will happened again. To solve it you need to save post id as e.g. `self.post_id` and use it in test methods instead of `1`:

```
class PostModelTest(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        post = Post.objects.create(text="just a test")
        self.post_id = post.pk  

    def test_text_content(self):
        post = Post.objects.get(id=self.post_id)
        expected_obect_name = f'{post.text}'
    self.assertEqual(expected_obect_name, 'just a test')
```

Comment: i had resorted to create the new object within the test function before you answered , but this works too